# Yii model behaviour in sub class inherits the AR model class

Tags: activerecord, yii, behavior

I have implemented a `crypt` behavior class that can be attached to a AR model so that, attached attributes will be stored as encrypted and retrieved as decrypted string.

```
class User extends CActiveRecord 
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return array(
            'crypt' => array(
            // this assumes that the behavior is in the folder: protected/behaviors/
            'class' => 'application.behaviors.CryptBehavior',
            // this sets that the attributes to be encrypted/decrypted are encryptedfieldname of the model
            'attributes' => array('password'),
            'useAESMySql' => true
           )
        );
    }
}
```

This is working fine. I am also having my custom class `Myuser` which extends `User` model to write my custom functions so that if i make some change in my `user` table and regenerate model, i wont loose my own functions.

If i move my `behavior` function to the class `MyUser`, **the behavior is not getting attached and not working as expected**.

```
class MyUser extends User 
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return array(
            'crypt' => array(
            // this assumes that the behavior is in the folder: protected/behaviors/
            'class' => 'application.behaviors.CryptBehavior',
            // this sets that the attributes to be encrypted/decrypted are encryptedfieldname of the model
            'attributes' => array('password'),
            'useAESMySql' => true
           )
        );
    }

    public function customfn1()
    {
         //some code goes here...
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Reference Link: [Crypt Behavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/26435-aes-encryption/page__view__findpost__p__127764)

Comment: i couldn't find cryptbehavior extension anywhere, is that your own behavior? can paste a rough outline of the behavior, just which class it extends, and which functions it implements/has will be enough.

Comment: updated the post with reference link !. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: no problem, lemme see if i can help

Comment: I think this blog gives me some roadmap to achieve what i want. http://invisipunk.blogspot.in/2011/01/yiis-activerecord-subclass-model-method.html

Comment: which version of yii is yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution. I need to test all the scenarios. Thanks to @bool.dev for your function.

```
class MyUser extends User 
{
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
       return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return array(
            'crypt' => array(
            // this assumes that the behavior is in the folder: protected/behaviors/
            'class' => 'application.behaviors.CryptBehavior',
           // this sets that the attributes to be encrypted/decrypted are encryptedfieldname of the model
            'attributes' => array('password'),
           'useAESMySql' => true
          )
       );
    }

   public static function getUserByID($id)
   {
      //validation of $id goes here..

      return MyUser::model()->findByPk($id);
   }
}
```

in my controller

```
$userModel = MyUser::getUserByID(1);
```

in my view

```
$userModel->password; //gives me the decrypted password; for easy understanding, i used password field here....
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll also have to add the `static model` function of the class to the subclass. Just this much should work:

```php
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}
```

Comment: actually the blog link that you gave is also right, but somewhere down the line of yii versions, that functionality was added. i will update answer with when this change occurred, and more details later, for now atleast you shouldn't be getting errors, with the answer.

Comment: trying to bring in some common practice not to touch the base model class. Thanks for your response. I am also looking for attaching behavior at DB component level, so that i can avoid this prob.

Comment: bool.dev do you live here? let me answer something! :P