# Yii, ActiveDateSelect must specify "model" and "attribute" or "name" property values

Tags: model, yii, gii

I am using [ActiveDateSelect](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/activedateselect/) extension to get the month, year details from the user. Everything goes fine. When i try to generate model using `gii` module i am getting the error. The stack trace says

```
\protected\extensions\ActiveDateSelect.php(120): CInputWidget->resolveNameID()
```

I can understand the problem by looking at the code of `CInputWidget` class. Not sure how to fix the error. If comment this extension configuration from `main.php` file, i am able to generate models using **gii**.

```
 'ActiveDateSelect' => array(
      'class' => 'ext.ActiveDateSelect',
  ),
```

Comment: I moved the code `list($name) = $this->resolveNameID()` from the `init()` function call to the `run()`. Its solved my problem and extension also working fine. But not sure it is a valid fix?

Comment: i don't think it's a valid fix, because looking at the source, `$name` is being used within the `init()` function again. Why are you  using trying extension configuration in `main.php`? Why not do it in the view directly? There could be another way to get this done, so let me know the answers to my queries, and maybe i could help you figure out a better solution.

Comment: @bool.dev, I have moved that code `... $this->field_order = strtoupper($this->field_order);` as well to `run()` function. Sorry i didnt mention it in my comments.
**Why are you using trying extension configuration in main.php?**
It will be autoloaded, i dont need to import where ever i am using this extension.

Comment: well that's where you are mistaken, let me type answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the real issue ([from comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085059/yii-activedateselect-must-specify-model-and-attribute-or-name-property-va#comment17781337_13085059)) seems that you want to autoload the extension. Well actually the way you are trying auto-loading is wrong, to autoload the extension do this instead(in *config/main.php*):

```php
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'ext.ActiveDateSelect' // add this line to the already existing import array
),
```

Now you can use in view directly like so:

```php
$this->widget('ActiveDateSelect', array (
    // whatever configuration
));
```

Or anywhere else like so:

```php
ActiveDateSelect::sanitize($model, 'birthdate'); // example from the extension's page
```

Comment: You are correct. I messed up b/w import & component section. Thanks !! Could you plz take a look at my one more post here. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084032/yii-model-behaviour-in-sub-class-inherits-the-ar-model-class]